# Hangman Game iterating over arrays with the for loop in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

So, earlier I posted a question asking how to run a string through a character array to make each letter equal a separate character value in an array.

I tried using a foreach loop and then labeling each object in the array "Guess" and then testing every value against the user-inputted value, but then I couldn't figure out how to output at the end of the loop if the user inputted a false value. instead of outputting every time the value was false against the array values since the loop is designed to do something for every value.

So I'm kind of stuck. I think there is a way to do it with a for loop but I'm still kind of noobish. I was wondering if anyone could help me please.

```
        char letter;
        int score = 0;
        string hangWord;

        //input inputs
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the hangman game!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 please enter a word.");
        hangWord = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        char[] hangCharacters = hangWord.ToCharArray();
        char[] asteriskWord = hangWord.ToCharArray();
        string displayWord;

        foreach (char guess in asteriskWord)
        {
            asteriskWord[guess] = '*';
        }
        while (score < 5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter please");

            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (char guess in hangCharacters)
            {                //How do I write a loop that tests all values and if none are correct
                             //displays "You guessed incorrectly"?
                letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                if( guess == letter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");
                    Console.WriteLine
                        //Also I don't know how to change the correct value      in the asteriskWord[] so that it displays
                        //only the character that was guessed in asteriskWord[]
                }

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Your score is " + score);
        if (displayWord == hangWord)
            Console.WriteLine("You Win! Thank you for playing!");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing! Try again!");
        }
```

Comment: Do not *cram everything* in one sinle method. Decompose your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Before the foreach take a bool flag as false, make it true inside the foreach only if the letter matches, otherwise will remain false. Test the condition after your iterations and display the message according to the flag state.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense! I would up vote up your comment but I'm still a noob. I need 4 more rep lol, but I'll keep you in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your logic around a little bit to see if the guess is in the hang characters. At the minute, you only check if the letter the user enters is the currently iterated letter

```
letter = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
if(hangCharacters.Any(c => c == letter))
    Console.WriteLine("You guessed correctly!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("You guessed incorrectly!");
```

To use the above you need to include `System.Linq`